# Compatibility of format files (*.fmt)

Tags: texlive, installing, format-files

What is the nature of format files and how much are they compatible between binaries / platforms?

I'm building my own amalgamated binary of several TeX programs (`kpsewhich`, `xetex`, `pdftex`, `bibtex8`, `luatex` for now). I've tried using my own custom xetex with the xetex format file produced by `install-tl`, but got:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2021/dev_busytexnative) (preloaded format=/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/dist-native/texlive/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt)
---! /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/dist-native/texlive/texmf-dist/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt made by different executable version
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I found this check in https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/5beaac4/texk/web2c/tex.ch#L3508, but I don't fully understand format file loading logic. I would be glad if anyone could explain it. E.g. maybe I could somehow bypass it if I know that it should be safe.

Must I always produce new format files if I'm using custom binaries?

I noticed that `install-tl` can use custom binaries, but what TeX programs does it need? E.g. I can provide it with `kpsewhich`, `xetex`, `pdftex`, `luatex`, `bibtex8` but if it requires more sophisticated utilities, it might be difficult to provide it. In other words, can I somehow provide only pdftex/xetex/luatex binaries to `install-tl` and let it use the rest from its standard operation?

(Prior to this attempt, I used my own custom format files, then it works well, so I have a workaround. I just tried to simplify my script and get rid of making the format files)

Comment: Ok, for me `install-tl` calls `fmtutil, fmtutil-sys, updmap, updmap-sys, kpseaccess, kpsereadlink, kpsestat, kpsewhich, mf-nowin, mktexlsr, luahbtex, luatex, pdftex, tex`. So should creating a `bin` directory with symlinks to these binaries and custom `*tex` wrappers be sufficient to make it use custom tex programs?